# Load Multi iframe with Colorbox ( With Next/Prev )

Tags: iframe, colorbox

am using colorbox to display iframe, but its possible to show next/Prev buttons same as Grouped Photo  ?
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Answer (score 1):

Depend on how you are planning on using the iframe.  But to group links together, use colorbox's rel property:

```
$('a.iframe').colorbox({rel:'my_iframes'});
```

Here, 'my_iframes' could be any identifier.  Just has to be something so that colorbox knows which elements to group together.